# NodeJS, MongoDB : Pass fetched data and display it on HTML

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I have written below code to get data from mongodb :

```
app.get('/StudentQuestionsPage',function(req,res){
    var questions="";
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } 
    else {
    console.log('Connection established to', url);  
    var collection = db.collection('studentQuestions');
    var cursor =collection.find();  

    fs.readFile( __dirname + '/StudentQuestionsPage.html', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
      var result = content;
      cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        result +=doc;
      }
        }); 
        res.send(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to pass the questions which is more than 1 to html file and want to show those questions there. I can see the questions are being fetched but I am not sure how I can display them on HTML. 
can someone help?

I have added below code :

```
app.get('/StudentQuestionsPage',function(req,res){  
var studentQuestions = mongoose.model('studentQuestion', studentQuestionSchema);

fs.readFile( __dirname + '/StudentQuestionsPage.html', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    var result = content;  
    res.send(result).status({studentQuestions:studentQuestions});
    mongoose.connection.close()
    });
});
```

But it does not print values on HTML. Below is the screenshot.[image]

Please let me know how to proceed. Sorry for pinging a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var questions = [
    { number: '1', text: 'question_1' },
    { number: '2', text: 'question_2' },
    { number: '3', text: 'question_3' },
];

res.send(result, {
    questions: questions});
```

In the code above instead of initializing an empty array, I am assuming that I have a pre defined array of questions. In the res.send() part of the code, add the code that I have written above this is to create a list of questions which we will use in the html file to display the questions. HTML file -

```
<h2>Questions</h2>
<ul>
<% questions.forEach(function(question) { %>
    <li>Number: <%= question.number %> - Text: <%= question.text %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

This way you can display the list of questions but here we have pre-defined the array. What you need to do is that instead of passing the data to the array yourself, you need to get it from the MongoDb. All you will need to do is change the field names according to the fields of you Database.

**EDIT**
Discard the hardcoded questions array.
I will now try to fetch data from the mongodb now. I hope you have mongoDb setup and good to go. Open mongod and mongo in different terminals and then run the code..

In server.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');//I am using mongoose which you can get by running sudo npm install mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName');//dbName is the database name from which you need to import the questions
```

This way you can fire a db in your node app.
Then you need to define your 'Question' dataset.

question.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', {
number: String,
text: String
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I am reading the values from MongoDB collection. I am storing it in to cursor and the values have to be passed to HTML. The example which you have given has already hardcoded value in for of array but in my case it is they are read from mongodb.

Comment: i know.. that i had left on you to do.. because your question asked how to display on the html page and you said that you are already able to fetch them. So just combine what you have with this and you should be good to go..

Comment: Okay now I have an updated version... See nodeJs resources on how to link mongo database if you still have issues. It is an easy step I guess