# How to fetch data from Mongodb and display it in respective html form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have successfully fetched and saved the data from a html form named inserted_data.html and saved in my mongobd, now i want to display that data in the form fields of another html file named user_info.html, how can i achieve this using Node.js, ejs and express?

here is the inserted_data.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="user_info.html" method="POST">
        username:<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
        your hobby:<input type="text" placeholder="hobby" name="hobby"><br>
        <button type="submit">sign in</button>
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the Action.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var MongoClient=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/";

app.listen(3000);

app.get("/inserted_data.html",function(req,res)
 {
   res.sendFile(__dirname+"/inserted_data.html");
 })

 app.get("/user_info.html",function(req,res)
 {
   res.sendFile(__dirname+"/user_info.html");
 })

 app.post("/user_info.html",function(req,res)
 {
   MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db)
    {
      if(err) throw err;
      var dbo=db.db("example");
      dbo.collection("stuff").insertOne(req.body);
    })
   console.log(req.body);
   res.redirect("/user_info.html");
 });
```

Here is the user_info.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="/">
        entered username:<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"><br>
        entered hobby:<input type="text" placeholder="hobby" name="hobby"><br>
        <button type="submit">sign in</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

i want to display the information stored in my database in the form fields of user_info.html
p.s. I believe this can be done using ejs but i have no experience with it so if anyone would be kind enough to explain how to do it, thank you in advance.

Comment: so , what is the problem ? Go to page you want to display the record and then create the structure you want to reprisent and then query against the table:)

Comment: i want data stored in my database to show up in form fields of user_info.html and i don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can query against the database table and present it? You do not knew how to query or how to display?

Comment: i can query data but don't know how to display it in respective form fields

Comment: i ant rome these part of programming at but here is good example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555613/nodejs-mongodb-pass-fetched-data-and-display-it-on-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS, MongoDB : Pass fetched data and display it on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555613/nodejs-mongodb-pass-fetched-data-and-display-it-on-html)